# ReactiveUI: How to pass an 'async' parameter to ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask()

Tags: c#, command, reactiveui

I have defined the `ReactiveCommand` like this:

```cs
CmdGetTestResult = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<bool>(async detailed =>
{
    var result = await Client.FooAsync(detailed);
});
CmdGetTestResult.ToPropertyEx(this, x => x.GetTestResultResponse);
```

`viewmodel`

```cs
public bool Detailed { get; set; }

public Unit GetTestResultResponse { [ObservableAsProperty]get; }
public ReactiveCommand<bool, Unit> CmdGetTestResult { get; }
```

In `xaml`:

```xml
<Button
    Content="get test result (F4)"
    Command="{Binding Path=ViewModel.CmdGetTestResult}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ViewModel.Detailed}"/>
```

The property `detailed` is `true` (checked in debugger), but it is always passed as `false`. What's wrng with my code?

EDIT:

I have also tried the `reactiveui` way:

```cs
this.BindCommand(ViewModel, model => model.CmdGetTestResult, window => window.ButtonGetTestResult, model => model.Detailed);
```

without any success and same problem..

Comment: Have you setup any sort of DataContext? -- we don't do that by default since we assume you are going to be using Reactive UI Binding.

Comment: DataContext is set in `MainWindow` and is working (Every other binding is working..). I have also tried the reactiveui way `this.BindCommand(ViewModel, model => model.CmdGetTestResult, window => window.ButtonGetTestResult, model => model.Detailed);`, but that did not work either.

Comment: Also generally in rxui we don't tend to use the parameter as much. Given you are getting the value direct from the view model why not get the value direct inside your method? You are protected from multiple runs of the same commamd  so unless you have other commands running the value of Detailed won't change.

Comment: Actually I use the value direct inside of my ViewModel as a 'workaround'. I thought that sth. is wrong with my code and for a kind of 'clean code', I wanted to use the parameter as well. So is there a bug in rx that this is not working?

Comment: I don't think there is, I would have to repo the command parameter approach. It's just RxUI tends to focus more on VM properties. Eg you can't use a parameter in canExecute for example.

Comment: It's just a little bit confusing. There is an overload (`ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask`) to use with a parameter and also the `this.BindCommand` wants a parameter, but it is not working. Maybe you should take a closer look. Actually I will use the property of the ViewModel to fix the problem.

Comment: Well one of the big reasons why we push the approach of using ViewModel properties for state information over parameters, is parameters is only supported on WPF/UWP based platforms. Given we are a MVVM framework for supporting xamarin/tizen based platforms as well, if you use properties you are limiting yourself on those platforms. See https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/binding-commands

Answer (score 0):

just been bumping my head and appears it's like that:

```
private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<List<LocationData>> _locations;
public ReactiveCommand<LocationData, List<LocationData>> GetLocations { get; }

public ViewModel 
{
   GetLocations = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<LocationData, List<LocationData>>(GetLocationsTask);
}

private async Task<List<LocationData>> GetLocationsTask(LocationData i)
{
       return await LocationService.GetLocationsAsync(i);
}
```

this is just a tester...